# Apache mod_rewrite rule as subdomain

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

How can be this

http://some-url.com/?lang=en

rewritten to this:

http://en.some-url.com ???

via mod_rewrite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define all possible languagespecific subdomains as ServerAlias in the VirtualHost-configfile of some-url.com and add following rewriterule

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^some-url\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} lang=(.*)$
RewriteRule . http://%1.some-domain.com/? [R=301,L]
```

In your serverside script you can get the actual language by checking SERVER/CGI variable called HTTP_HOST (in php this would be `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` while in ColdFusion this would be `#CGI.HTTP_HOST#`)