# RewriteRule not triggered

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, apache2

I'm trying to change from

```
http://www.myhost.com/en/team/league-of-legends/3798/destiny
```

to

```
http://lol.myhost.com/en/team/league-of-legends/3798/destiny
```

I tryed different combinaisons for my Apache2 server including the following :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)/team/league-of-legends/(.*)/(.*)  http://lol.myhost.com/$1/team/league-of-legends/$2/$3 [R=301,L]
```

But it seems not to work (i checked in an htaccess tester).
**What am I doing wrong please ?**

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10368298/apache-mod-rewrite-rule-as-subdomain

Comment: the only thing it has in common is that it's both url-rewritting. that's all. I don't see anything other in common.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?myhost\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}   ^/([^/]+)/team/league-of-legends/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?  [NC]
RewriteRule .  http://lol.myhost.com/%1/team/league-of-legends/%2/%3    [R=301,L,NC]
```

Redirects permanently

`http://www.myhost.com/en/team/league-of-legends/3798/destiny` or

`http://myhost.com/en/team/league-of-legends/3798/destiny`

To:

`http://lol.myhost.com/en/team/league-of-legends/3798/destiny`

Strings `en`, `3798` and `destiny` are assumed to be variable, while `team` and  `league-of-legends` are assumed to be fixed.

For silent mapping, remove `R=301` from `[R=301,L,NC]`

Comment: The strings are dynamic, /en/ is dynamic, /3798/ and /destiny are also dynamic

Comment: I will update my answer. Those "details" should be in the question because they are hard to guess.

Comment: Well, my answer works in `htaccess.madewithlove.be` and in any other server so did it work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory of `www.myhost.com` domain:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(myhost\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/team/league-of-legends/ http://lol.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: does not work, it outputs : `http://lol.myhost.com/en/player/league-of-legends/3798/destiny3798/destiny` instead of `......./3798/destiny`

Comment: @Tristan: I now about that site and have experienced that it is not best place to test out .htaccess rules. e.g on that site this RewriteRule will work: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://lol.%1/$1 [R=301,L,NC]` instead of RewriteRule line above.

Answer (score 0):

See if this works. Let me know if it doesn't.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^\/]*)/team/league-of-legends/(.*)$  http://lol.myhost.com/$1/team/league-of-legends/$2 [R=301,L]
```